# How to target Manager in Organization Tab

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to update a specific user's Organization tab for the field Manager. But when running the code it is saying an error "Reason: 'Cannot find an object with identity: 'Bob Bill'. Although the user object 'Bob Bill' does exist in the same OU.

```
get-aduser -SearchBase "CN=Abraham Solis,OU=Users,OU=OU IT,DC=chcm,DC=local" 
           -Filter * | set-aduser -Manager "Bob Bill"
```

Comment: use Bob Bill's SamAccountName or DistinguishedName or GUID or SID